# Is there any way to access profile name and profile pic of those users who posts in a page in facebook using the Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook's Graph API to access posts and comments of users in a facebook page. I can get their posts but I can't access their profile name or profile picture. Is there any way to access their profile information via graph API.

Comment: is your Facebook app already reviewed?

Comment: No, it is not reviewed. Can I get the user information after the Facebook review?